# AWS lambda: out of pty devices

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, pexpect

I'm trying to use the pexpect library within an AWS lambda, but I'm getting the following error:

```
[ERROR] OSError: out of pty devices
```

It turns out that any code that contains pty.spawn() fails in a lambda. Here's a minimal piece of code for a failing lambda:

```
import json
import pty

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    pty.spawn('ls')
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

The equivalent expect code is also pretty basic:

```
cmd = f'sftp -i my_key_file -q username@server'
child = pexpect.spawn(cmd, encoding='utf-8')
```

The resulting exception is:

```
[ERROR] OSError: out of pty devices
Traceback (most recent call last):
   ...

    child = pexpect.spawn(...)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pexpect/pty_spawn.py", line 205, in __init__
    self._spawn(command, args, preexec_fn, dimensions)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pexpect/pty_spawn.py", line 304, in _spawn
    cwd=self.cwd, **kwargs)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pexpect/pty_spawn.py", line 315, in _spawnpty
    return ptyprocess.PtyProcess.spawn(args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ptyprocess/ptyprocess.py", line 230, in spawn
    pid, fd = pty.fork()
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/pty.py", line 96, in fork
    master_fd, slave_fd = openpty()
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/pty.py", line 29, in openpty
    master_fd, slave_name = _open_terminal()
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/pty.py", line 59, in _open_terminal
    raise OSError('out of pty devices')
[ERROR] OSError: out of pty devices Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Comment: Did you ever fix this?

Comment: No. I switched to some alternative solution that doesn't rely on expect @SamBecker

Comment: I had same error on Centos7, when "dev/pts" wasn't properly mounted. I guess this may help next time. Check mount on this like a:

$ mount | grep dev/pts

________________________________________________________
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)